# Merging and Tranforming Array of object in javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i have two array of object like this...

```
const planned = [
    {
        '2023-01-06': 46,
        '2023-01-04': 45,
        '2023-01-05': 43,
        '2023-01-07': 53
    }
]
const actual =[
    {
        "2023-01-07": 12,
        "2023-01-06": 16,
        "2023-01-04": 14,
        "2023-01-08": 10,
        "2023-01-05": 12,
        "2023-01-03": 10
    }
]
```

i try to merge it into one array of object that separated the date and the value, here is my expected array:

```
const transformed =  [{
    date:"2023-01-03",
    actual:10,
    planned:0,
  },{
    date:"2023-01-05",
    actual:10,
    planned:5,
  },{
    date:"2023-01-06",
    actual:16,
    planned:46,
  },....
```

]
here is my try:

```
const transformed = planned.map((el)=>{
  let obj ={}
  actual.map((els)=>{
     if(el.key === els.key){
       obj["date"]=== el.key
       obj["actual"]=== el.keys
       obj["planned"]=== el.key
     }
  })
 return {...obj}
})
```

i try to figure it out, but have some issues on how to create the logic... anyone here to give me clue on it? can we use reduce prototype array or any built in?, any help on this will be verry thankful

Comment: This is exactly the same as [Merging and Tranforming Array of object in javascript](/q/75053199/4642212), but from a [different account](/users/20619226/nabati-admin) to circumvent rate limiting, which violates the site rules.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah i try to give an example on what i've try, but my question already got closed..., thats why i ask again with example of my try..

Comment: The correct procedure is to vote for it to be reopened or submit your edit to review and just wait for it to be reopened, not repost the same question on an alternative account.

Comment: sorry about that, but i already submit my edit, out of sudden it got deleted by system... which i don;t know why...

Comment: What is it about 01-03, 01-05, and 01-06 that qualify them for the output, but not the other dates in planned and actual?

Comment: @danh uhm.. pardon me... 01-03 just the date and there is two arrays one is the planned and the second is the actual.... i just wanna try to group it into my expected array in the question...

Comment: @18-15 The original question clearly states that you deleted it yourself. Anyway, you misunderstood danh’s question. Why are only `"2023-01-03"`, `"2023-01-05"`, and `"2023-01-06"` in `transformed`, but not the others?

Comment: @danh i get it, it just an example.. but it should contained all of the dates not only the ones that you mentioned, i really dont know about that because i clicked on edit button...

Comment: I think thats is typo..., sorry for my bad explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach. `planned` and `actual` are arrays, so we first convert them to a flat map and then use this map to create the output

```js
const planned = [
    {
        "2023-01-06": 46,
        "2023-01-04": 45,
        "2023-01-05": 43,
        "2023-01-07": 53,
    },
];
const actual = [
    {
        "2023-01-07": 12,
        "2023-01-06": 16,
        "2023-01-04": 14,
        "2023-01-08": 10,
        "2023-01-05": 12,
        "2023-01-03": 10,
    },
];

const convertToMap = (list) =>
    list.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});

const actualStats = convertToMap(actual);
const plannedStats = convertToMap(planned);

const dates = [
    ...new Set([...Object.keys(actualStats), ...Object.keys(plannedStats)]),
];

const transformed = dates.map((date) => ({
    date,
    planned: plannedStats[date] || 0,
    actual: actualStats[date] || 0,
}));

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: Can we make it to 0 if theres is no value on the planned array instead of removing it?...

Comment: Like this {
    date:"2023-01-03",
    actual:10,
    planned:0,
  } it dont have value on the planned array but instead of not showing it can we change it to 0?... @AbitoPrakash

Comment: Have edited the answer, please check again

Comment: Yes... if there is no value on planned can we jsut make it to 0 like i state on my question? @AbitoPrakash...

Comment: uhm i got bugs here..., if there is date on planned but not on actual... its not showing...,any help on that... its the vice versa of the ones i states above....,
{ date:"2023-01-09", actual:0, planned:10, }

Comment: ur code works perfectly... thanks a lot..., just a few bug i mention above, maybe u can help me with that..., once again thankyou so much... @AbitoPrakash

Comment: Edited the snippet again, please check. In the new approach we combine all the dates in actual and planned and then iterate over them to create the transformed response